# Bootstrap one-page layout viewport width units

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a simple one-page layout in Bootstrap, however I'm struggling with the background color of a div on a large screen and on a mobile. When on a large screen, the size of the div is 100vw wide and 100vh high - it's all fine. The problem is when I scale down the viewport, the div doesn't have the desired color underneath all it's contents, the contents overflow into the second div underneath the first one.

How can I make the div have always one color underneath all it's contents no matter what the viewport size is? (width or height of 100% did not help really, there were borders on sides).

Thanks

Comment: Add `clearfix` to your div.

Comment: the clearfix helped for the container-fluid to be fullwidth, is there a way I can have the height of the div at least 100vh? if the viewport is able to display all the div's contents, it'll be 100vh high, if it needs to expand it's height, it would do so

Comment: okay, i figured it out, thanks for the help anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean just add a background color to the div?

**CSS**

```
.my__div {
  background: red; // add background color
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="my__div">Some content here</div>
```